# Keyboard shortcut to set gnome-terminal tab title

Tags: linux, keyboard-shortcuts, gnome-terminal

I like to work in Linux without using the mouse, because of that I would like to know if there is any method to set a keyboard shortcut to set gnome-terminal tab title.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

From Edit -> Keyboard Shortcuts... you can set a shortcut to Set Title. I don't have a default one.